# Sending two forms after button click and run php in background

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, forms

I have created this site and integrated with payfast, it works well. but now i want to execute another php script on **place order button** which gets details into the **db**
here is my code quite long.... I no nothing about Ajax or javascript!! Please help

```html
<form id="form1" action="payment.php" method="POST">
           some stuff...    
            </form>

<?php
$htmlForm = '<form action="https://'.$pfHost.'/eng/process" method="post" id="form2">';
  
$htmlForm .= '<input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-flat" value="PLace Order" onclick="submitForms()"></form>';
?>

            <?php
           echo" 
            ".$htmlForm."
          </div>";
                }
                else{
                  echo '...';      
                }
              ?> 
          
<script>
submitForms = function() {
   document.getElementById("form1").submit();
   document.getElementById("form2").submit();
}
</script>
```

```js
 $(function() {
  $(".submit").click(function() {
      var uid = $("#uid").val();
        var prodtls = $("#prodtls").val();
        var fname = $("#fname").val();
        var amnt = $("#amnt").val();
        var mail = $("#mail").val();

  var dataString = 'uid='+ uid + '&prodtls=' + prodtls + '&fname' +fname + '&amnt' + amnt + '&mail' + mail;

if(time=='' || date=='')
{
  $('.success').fadeOut(200).hide();
  $('.error').fadeOut(200).show();
}
else
{
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "payment.php",
    data: dataString,
    success: function(){
     $('.success').fadeIn(200).show();
     $('.error').fadeOut(200).hide();
    }
  });
}
return false;
});
});
```

I tried the ajax i found but, it never worked. Check at the end of my code!
What i need is **payment.php** will execute in the background while it directs user to **payfast**

I want to submit only the first one via AJAX.

Comment: At Stackoverflow we don't provide tutorials, and we don't write complete features for ou, from nothing. If you know nothing about AJAX, you need to spend some time studying it - we cannot teach you in a single Stackoverflow post. And if we simply give you all the code, you wouldn't understand it enough. Instead, show the AJAX code you tried and explain what problem(s) you encountered, specifically, and then we can help you with that. Also, please make sure the code you provide is a [mre] of your issue - we don't want a mountain of irrelevant stuff to wade through. See also [ask]. Thanks.

Comment: @ADyson I have edited the code please check above.

Comment: Thanks. But that doesn't include your AJAX attempt, or any kind of useful problem description. Please re-read what was requested.

Comment: @ADyson i have added the ajax i tried, it executes but i dont get value on the other form

Comment: 1) you need to use `preventDefault()` to stop the form also doing the default postback behaviour (and thus refreshing the page) - see https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/ . 2) It's unclear whether the first form also has a button with `class="submit"` on it, because you didn't show that. And anyway, this code simply handles the user clicking on submit on the second form. To make it also submit the first form, you'd need to write a second AJAX request to submit that one. 3) You need to get rid of the `onclick="submitForms()"` bit.

Comment: Also, are you wanting to submit both forms via AJAX, or perhaps do you want to submit the first one via AJAX, and then do a regular postback for the second one? It wasn't quite clear.

Comment: i want to submit only the first one via AJAX . Sorry onclick i added when i was trying a different script i didn't use it on ajax. I used an ID on AJAX. And yes submit was there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempt doesn't make much sense because it doesn't appear to target the first form (which you say you want) and may not prevent the default postback behaviour.

As I understand it, you want that whichever form the user clicks on to submit, the code will actually then submit the first form via AJAX, and then the second one via standard postback.

This should do the job:

HTML:

```
<form id="form1" class="doubleForm" action="payment.php" method="post">
    <input type="submit" id="submit1" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-flat" value="Submit">
</form>

<form id="form2" class="doubleForm" action="https://example.com/eng/process" method="post">';
  <input type="submit" id="submit2" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-flat" value="Place Order">
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
//handle submission of both forms
$(".doubleForm").submit(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); //stop standard postback

  var uid = $("#uid").val();
  var prodtls = $("#prodtls").val();
  var fname = $("#fname").val();
  var amnt = $("#amnt").val();
  var mail = $("#mail").val();
  var dataString = 'uid='+ uid + '&prodtls=' + prodtls + '&fname' +fname + '&amnt' + amnt + '&mail' + mail;

  if(time == '' || date == '')
  {
    $('.success').fadeOut(200).hide();
    $('.error').fadeOut(200).show();
  }
  else
  {
    //submit first form via AJAX
    var request = $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "payment.php",
      data: dataString
    });

    request.done(function(response) {
      $('.success').fadeIn(200).show();
      $('.error').fadeOut(200).hide();
    
      //now the first form is submitted and server has responded, we can trigger "normal" (non-AJAX) submission of second form
      document.querySelector("#form2").submit();
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: FYI I don't know where you have defined `time` or `date`, so I have no idea if that `if` statement will work as intended. Also, I don't know what fields are in your form1, but it's possible you could just use jQuery's `.serialize()` to collect all the form data, instead of building up the dataString manually like that. If there are no fields you want to exclude from the submission, then that would make more sense (it would also automatically ensure all the data is correctly url-encoded, which would be a good thing).

Comment: There are input fields with the above IDs on the form so .serialize() could do, but let me try it manually first and see

Comment: No problem. If you use `serialize()`, make sure all the fields have correct `name` attributes, rather than `id`s.

Answer (score 0):

So this actually worked well using `.serialize()`. Thanks @ADyson for the headsup just had to tweak it a little bit, though i'm not experienced in **js**

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $("#submit2").click(function(){
            var dataString = $("#form1").serialize();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "payment.php",
                data: dataString,
                success: function(data)
                {
                    alert('Success!');
                    $("#form1")[0].reset();
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```